# embedded url in javascript code

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

i think there is a partial url in here but cant read it. ie

i have www.website.com/

and need the next part

```
$j('.get-code').live('click', function() {
    linkId = $j(this).attr("id");
    codeId = linkId.replace("get-code-day-", "");
    voucherCode = $j("#voucher-code-day-" + codeId).val();

    $j.post("/promotions/ajax/add-user-voucher", {
        voucherCode: voucherCode
    }, function(xml) {
        if ($j("status", xml).text() == "1") {
           // do something on success
        } else {
            showUIDialog("<p>A problem occurred: " + $j("error", xml).text() + "</p>");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: not sure what you mean... are you trying to parse the javascript to extract some url? is your javascript trying to extract some url from some part of the dom?

Comment: yeah sorry, i am wanting the url from this code